# Why does Maven test not work after mvn clean unless I run mvn update?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cucumber, bamboo

I'm running some service testing using restassured and cucumber and they work fine locally just using Maven test.

The issue is if I run Maven clean, then I must run Maven update or it will not work (Says it can't find my Cucumber feature files). For reference it says:

```
No features found at [classpath:classpath/classpath]
```

This wouldn't be a huge issue except I need to have this running through Bamboo where I can't call Maven update.

So I either need to figure out what is wrong with my POM to begin with to cause this issue, or how I can run Maven update through the goals/environment variables.

The POM is fairly simple, only having the needed dependencies/reporting stuff.
The build part of the POM is as follows:

```
<build>
    <finalName>Test</finalName>
    <directory>target</directory>
    <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

This is all in Java 8 using Eclipse as the IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid specifying anything in the build section in my pom and instead use the default values.

That is, I would keep my feature files in the same package as the runner or a sub package.

The runner could for example live in the package `se/thinkcode/tage`
As in the directory:

```
./test/java/se/thinkcode/tage
```

This means that the feature files should live in the directory:

```
./test/resources/se/thinkcode/tage
```

This would allow me to minimize the configuration in the runner. I typically use runners that looks like this:

```
package se.thinkcode.tage;

import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class RunCukesTest {
}
```

This is the smallest configuration possible if you want to run Cucumber using JUnit from Maven.

It is even smaller that the example supplied by the Cucumber team: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I currently have all of the test/feature files under the same package. I figured that was the easiest way to get it to work. I will have to give this a shot tomorrow. If it works I'll happily mark this as correct.

Comment: Just noting that this did end up working for me! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like defining the features/glue in the cucumber options fixed this. 
I do believe there is a better option though.

I added the following cucumber options:

```
    features ="src/test/java",
    glue = "packagename",
```